# Unity - Line of light through FBX corners

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, fbx

I'm trying to make a room in Blender. I started with a cube, then extruded its faces, finally I exported it as FBX and imported it in Unity.

The shadow from the sun makes a strange line of light coming out of the corner of the room as you can see in the image below.

[image]

I've made more rooms and I have the same problem in every corner.

[image]

Here it is in Blender:

[image]

Any idea about what is causing the problem?

Comment: Usually this is caused by the verticies at the corners of the model not being welded, so the lighting engine sees a very narrow gap (even though you and I would say that the width of that gap is 0).

Comment: But I extruded them so how could they not be welded?

Comment: I am not a 3D modeler, I only know that when there've been very tiny gaps in the geometry that you get that effect. How Blender does extrusions, I don't know. Its possible that Blender creates the geometry in a way that leaves those gaps, maybe its something else.  If it isn't that, oh well, I guessed and was wrong.

Comment: Try removing unnecessary verts such as the ones between the door and the corner, e.g. : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html

Comment: I tried removing them with ctrl+x (dissolve) but the line of light is still present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here https://answers.unity.com/questions/925812/unity-5-real-time-lights-cast-shadows-with-gaps-li.html, I had to set the normal bias to 0 in the directional light of my scene.

But with the normal bias set to 0, weird shapes appear in the editor but also in the game view...

[image]

However the second solution which is to set `Cast Shadow` to `Two Sided` seems to work.